# adding google search to UISearchBar in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uisearchbar

I am new to iphone development. I want to add the google search to my application. How can I add google search to my UISearchBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for key up events, fire off requests to Google's API for Search; present the returned results as a UITableView of suggestions. When a user taps on a suggestion, load the query.

Were you asking for how to do it, or *code* to do it? We're not a website for the latter.